# MODULE_LICENSE is defined but undetected in linux kernel 5.X

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I have a simple kernel module with multiple objects. When I compile it, it prompts me that MODULE_LICENSE is missing. It's defined in the main.o but somehow undetected by the compiler:

```
make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=`pwd` modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/kernels/5.14.0-105.el9.x86_64'
  CC [M]  /tmp/linux5-multi-files/util.o
  LD [M]  /tmp/linux5-multi-files/main.o
  MODPOST /tmp/linux5-multi-files/Module.symvers
ERROR: modpost: missing MODULE_LICENSE() in /tmp/linux5-multi-files/main.o
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.modpost:150: /tmp/linux5-multi-files/Module.symvers] Error 1
make[2]: *** Deleting file '/tmp/linux5-multi-files/Module.symvers'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1792: modules] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/kernels/5.14.0-105.el9.x86_64'
make: *** [Makefile:5: build] Error 2
```

On older Linux (centos 6-7) it works fine, but on CentOS 8 and CentOS 9, it no longer works. What was wrong? I've attached all the files.

-- attached all files --

Makefile

```
main-objs := util.o
obj-m += main.o

build:
    make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=`pwd` modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=`pwd` clean
```

main.c

```
#include "util.h"

static void __exit cleanup(void)
{
   
}

static int __init startup(void)
{
    test();
    return 0;
}

module_init(startup);
module_exit(cleanup);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Linux");
```

util.h

```
#ifndef UTIL_H
#define UTIL_H

#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

void test(void);

#endif
```

util.c

```
#include "util.h"

void test()
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "whatever\n");
}
```

Comment: Don't tag irrelevant languages.

Comment: @ikegami Ah, didn't notice that. stackoverflow automatically added c++ as a tag

Comment: Tags aren't added automatically. It won't even let you post unless you add a tag.

Answer (score 1):

To further debug this issue, I've added `-v` to the ccflags, and main.c is not even compiled on CentOS 8!

So far it looks like the module name can't be the same as the object name, so I have to modify the makefile to something like this:

```
xxx-objs := main.o util.o
obj-m += xxx.o
```

And the problem is gone.